# How to Detect and Handle Swipe-to-Go-Back Gesture in Flutter App Navigation?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter app where I navigate to a new page using the Get package's **`Get.toNamed`** method like this: `final result = await Get.toNamed(Routes.EDIT_PROFILE);`. I'm also using Get.back(result: {"userData": data}); to return data when the user goes back from the EDIT_PROFILE page.

This works perfectly when the user clicks on the back button in the app bar. However, I've noticed that on iOS, when the user performs a swipe-to-go-back gesture from the left edge of the screen, I can't return data in this case. I'm looking for a way to detect and handle the swipe-to-go-back gesture on iOS so that I can still return data when the user swipes to navigate back. Is there a specific Flutter or Get package solution for this issue?

---

I tried with the `WillPopScope` widget but after adding that, the user lost the swipe-to-go-back gesture functionality.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('TestView'),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async{
      print("swipe-to-go-back gesture run");
      return true;
    },
    child: const Center(
      child: Text(
        'TestView is working',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Page inside a WillPopScope and implement the onWillPop

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

See a full example in the docs.

Comment: after adding WillPopScope, the user loose the swipe-to-go-back gesture functionality.

Comment: How did you implement it? Add it to your qestion.

Comment: I edited my question please review that.